# Printing mistake with System.print

Tags: printing, system

I'm trying to print each one a seperate line. for example it should come out like this.

```
Name:
Phone: 
Car: 
Type of Work:
```

But for some reason it comes out like this

```
Name:
Phone: Car:
```

Here's the code:

```
    System.out.print("  Name:");
    String name = input.next();
    System.out.print("  Phone:");
    String phone = input.next();
    System.out.print("  Car:");
    String car = input.next();
    System.out.print("  Type of work:");
    String work = input.next();
  }
}
```

I tried changing the System.out.println but it wont let you type the input on the same line, it automatically bumps you down to the next line

Answer (score 0):

Emulating a println but after the input should work.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("  Name:");
        String work = input.next();
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println("  Phone:");
        String work = input.next();
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println("  Car:");
        String work = input.next();
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println("  Type of work:");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes but once you have println for an input, it wont let you type the input on the same line, it automatically bumps you down to the next line

Comment: Gotcha, my bad. couldn't you just do a `System.out.print("\n");` after each input? So that you're basically emulating a println but after the input?